# Suppress console log of successful mocha tests

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, winston

When running mocha test suite, my console output is polluted with application logs. Is there an easy way to suppress these logs from successful tests? I'm able to suppress all logs for testing environment, however I'd like to see logs from failed tests. I'm using [Winston](https://github.com/winstonjs/winston) as logging library.

Comment: How would the logger know which tests are going to fail?

Comment: Of course, logger doesn't know it. But it should be possible to stack all the logs in a queue and if test is successful, queue is flushed, and if not stacked logs are sent to console. So the question is, if somebody already tried to do this, or should I try by myself...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could set up a separate Winston transport when running tests that will write logs to a logfile, and show the contents of that file if the test failed:

```
afterEach(function() {
  if (this.currentTest.state !== 'failed') return;
  console.log( fs.readFileSync('/your/logfile').toString() );
});
```

Before each test you'd remove the file to start fresh:

```
beforeEach(function(done) {
  try { fs.unlinkSync('/your/logfile'); } catch(e) {}
});
```